# Adding a scanned item to the total using a method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a method (add:) that will add a products price to the overall total when scanned.  Here is what I have, but it doesn't work.

```
var cashRegister = {
    total: 0,
//insert the add method here    

    add: function (itemCost){
     if(var i = this.itemCost; i >=0; i++){
         return cashRegister.total + this.itemCost;
         }

    },

    scan: function (item) {
        switch (item) { 
        case "eggs": 
            this.add(0.98); 
            break;

        case "milk": 
            this.add(1.23); 
            break;

        //Add other 2 items here
        case "magazine":
            this.add(4.99);
            break;
        case "chocolate":
            this.add(0.45);
            break;

        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: How doesn't it work?

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error.

Comment: lol sorry, its:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

Comment: open the console to see the error if exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cashRegister = {
    total: 0,
    //insert the add method here    

    add: function (itemCost) {
        if (itemCost >= 0) {
            this.total += itemCost;
        }
    },

    scan: function (item) {
        switch (item) {
            case "eggs":
                this.add(0.98);
                break;

            case "milk":
                this.add(1.23);
                break;

                //Add other 2 items here
            case "magazine":
                this.add(4.99);
                break;
            case "chocolate":
                this.add(0.45);
                break;

        }
        return true;
    }
};

cashRegister.scan('eggs');
cashRegister.scan('magazine');

alert(cashRegister.total);
```

There ya go. Your if statement in add() was way off. Here's the fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/c453Lx4r/1/

Answer (score 0):

You maybe mix up *if* and *for* statmens. Just replace *if* with *for* and it should work.

Comment: If he "fixes" that, then his program will infinite loop, lol. Idk what he's trying to do there.

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar, you are right. Idk too. Maybe he forgot to add 2nd parameter to add function something like "times".

Comment: I'm learning JS through an online course and it's asking me to create an add method to add a scanned item to the cart total.